# Fluent API Producing Duplicate Columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

We are trying to reconfigure our EF project so that we use fluent API configuration instead of data annotations for cleaner data models. We have existing tables and I'm now attempting to validate my efforts.

Here are the old (partial) EF model declarations:

```
[Table("CustomerLocation")]
internal class CustomerLocationEF
{
    [Column(Order = 0), Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1), Key]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(ModelConstants.MaxLength128)]
    [Index("IX_Customer_LocationReference", IsUnique = true)]
    public string LocationReference { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerEF Customer { get; set; }
}
[Table("Customer")]
internal class CustomerEF
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomerLocationEF> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

These work fine and produce the expected schema. However, here are the new models and configuration:

```
public class CustomerLocationModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string LocationReference { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomerLocationModel> Locations { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class CustomerLocationTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CustomerLocationModel>
{
    public CustomerLocationTypeConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("CustomerLocation");

        HasKey(x => new {x.CustomerId, x.LocationReference});

        Property(x => x.CustomerId)
            .HasColumnName("CustomerID");

        HasRequired(x => x.Customer).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

However, this tries to generate a table like this:

```
CreateTable(
        "dbo.CustomerLocation",
        c => new
            {
                CustomerID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                LocationReference = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                CustomerModel_Id = c.Int(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.CustomerID, t.LocationReference })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Customer", t => t.CustomerID)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Customer", t => t.CustomerModel_Id)
        .Index(t => new { t.CustomerID, t.LocationReference }, unique: true, name: "IX_Customer_LocationReference")
        .Index(t => t.CustomerModel_Id);
```

Notice the duplicate column `CustomerModel_Id` and associated foreign key. I've run into issues like this before with data annotations and resolved them with a `[ForeignKey]`, but I'm new to Fluent API and unsure about what I am doing wrong here. How do I resolve this in Fluent so that it picks up my navigation property/foreign key properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was in the mapping config for the `CustomerModel`, once I cleaned that up, my problem went away:

```
HasMany(x => x.Locations)
                .WithRequired(x => x.Customer)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.CustomerId);
```